# Не происходит переход на другие активити

Tags: java, android, activity

Не могу понять, что не так. Не осуществляется переход на другие активити при нажатии кнопок.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button fBtn,sBtn,tBtn;

        fBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fBtn);
        fBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Send your homework to BUTTON BOSS",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent2 = new Intent(getApplication(),HWPage.class);
                startActivity(intent2);
            }
    });
        sBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sBtn);
        sBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent3 = new Intent(getApplication(),Alert.class);
                startActivity(intent3);
            }
        });
        tBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tBtn);
        tBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent4 = new Intent(getApplication(),Alerts.class);
                startActivity(intent4);
            }
        });
    }
```

Стек-трейс:

```
    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.annah.third, PID: 3873
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.annah.third/com.example.annah.third.Alert}: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.example.annah.third.Alert> has no zero argument constructor
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2548)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
    Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.example.annah.third.Alert> has no zero argument constructor
       at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1078)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2538)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Второе активити

```
public class Alert {
    public String alert_head;
    public String alert_date;
    public Alert(String alert_head, String alert_date){
        this.alert_head = alert_head;
        this.alert_date = alert_date;
    }
}
```

Адаптер

```
public class AlertAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AlertAdapter.Holder>{
    private List<Alert> alertList;

    public AlertAdapter(List<Alert> alertList){
        this.alertList = alertList;
    }

    @Override
    public Holder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.notiflist,parent,false);

        return new Holder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(Holder holder, int position) {
        Alert alert = alertList.get(position);
        holder.alert_head.setText(alert.alert_head);
        holder.alert_date.setText(alert.alert_date);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return alertList.size();
    }

    class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView alert_head;
        public TextView alert_date;

        public Holder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            alert_head = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.alert_head);
            alert_date = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.alert_date);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: думаю есть еще ошибка тут `tBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fBtn);` нужно `tBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tBtn);`

Comment: @Saidolim, да, спасибо, невнимательность

Comment: А Ваши `activity` в `AndroidManifest.xml` прописаны?

Comment: @post_zeew да, сейчас не переходит только вторая кнопка. Это может быть ошибка в следующей активити?

Comment: Да, может. Покажите стек-трейс.

Comment: @post_zeew не знаю, как его посмотреть

Comment: Вы нажимаете на кнопку. Что происходит дальше? Появляется *ошибка*? Стек-трейс находится вот тут: https://developer.android.com/studio/images/debug/android-monitor-logcat_2-2_2x.png

Comment: @post_zeew да,ошибка, добавила стек-трейс

Comment: Еще добавьте код активити, при запуске которой происходит ошибка.

Comment: @post_zeew добавила

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что класс:

```
public class Alert {
    public String alert_head;
    public String alert_date;

    public Alert(String alert_head, String alert_date)
    {
        this.alert_head = alert_head;
        this.alert_date = alert_date;
    }
```

не является никоим образом `activity`.

Для того, чтобы он стал `activity`, его необходимо наследовать от соответствующего класса, например, от `AppCompatActivity` и реализовать соответствующие методы, типа `onCreate(...)`.

Возможно, в строке:

```
Intent intent3 = new Intent(getApplication(), Alert.class);
```

Вы хотели вместо `Alert.class` написать что-то другое.